# Windows Forms Timer not executed on time

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, livecharts

I am using a System.Windows.Forms.Timer in my application which triggers a method that adds new data to four LiveCharts. The interval is set to 1000 ms. It works fine for like the first one or two minutes but then the interval gets bigger and bigger and after 10 minutes it triggers only every 15 seconds or so.
I have tried using different Timers without any luck. Might it be that the performance of the application/LiveCharts is just too bad and because the timer runs on the UI thread it has to wait for the application to be "ready"?

Thanks!

Timer setup

```
graphRefreshTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
graphRefreshTimer.Interval = 1000;
graphRefreshTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(refreshUI);
graphRefreshTimer.Start();
```

refreshUI (basically just adding new ChartValues to the LiveCharts. Takes a maximum of 100 ms to run)

```
    //...
B1VoltageValues.Add(new MeasureModel
                {
                    DateTime = now,
                    Value = Convert.ToDouble(B1.Voltage) / 1000
                });

B1CurrentValues.Add(new MeasureModel
                {
                    DateTime = now,
                    Value = Convert.ToDouble(B1.Current) / 1000
                });

B1ChargingCapacityValues.Add(new MeasureModel
                {
                    DateTime = now,
                    Value = Convert.ToDouble(B1.getChargeCapIfTrue()) / 1000
                });

B1DischargingCapacityValues.Add(new MeasureModel
                {
                    DateTime = now,
                    Value = Convert.ToDouble(B1.getDischargeCapIfTrue()) / 1000
                });

B1EnergyValues.Add(new MeasureModel
                {
                    DateTime = now,
                    Value = Convert.ToDouble(B1.Energy) / 1000
                });
//...
```

Comment: Yes. If the code within the timer takes too long then the timer cannot run on the interval you want. It can only run one at a time and will skip.

Comment: I have measured how long it takes to execute the code in the method that gets triggered but it never exceeds 100 ms.

Comment: Timer is only guaranteed to run __no faster__ than the Interval tells it to. If you need more percision either use a different timer or a smaller Intervall with your own timing control.. But your question sounds as if the issue is not with the Timer at all. Post the code and/or tell more about what the Tick does/triggeres!

Comment: I suspect if you comment out the method being called for chart updates,  your timer will continue to fire at the expected interval.

Comment: The Tick event handler can only run when your UI thread is not otherwise busy doing something else.  So plain conclusion you can draw that it *is* busy, should be readily visible from Task Manager.  Having the UI thread burn 100% core is something you must always avoid.  Always calling Add() and never removing data from the graph is an obvious possible cause.

Comment: The application is used to show data of different batteries over the time frame of multiple hours. Every second new data is pulled from the batteries. Problem is that the graphs should always show the data of the complete charging process of the batteries, so I can't really remove any data from the chart.

Comment: If I comment out the adding of the Measure Models of all four batteries, it works fine. But as soon as I add the data of only one battery it starts to go downhill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to use the LiveCharts.Geared package which can handle way more data that the standard one. No further freezes of the UI occured after using this package.